# static ipv6 route into a lxc container

Tags: ipv6

I want to route an ipv6 ip to a lxc-container, but the packets are not forwarded. I do not want to bridge the lxc-containers to eth0 and i do not want to use autoconfig. Further i only have a `/64` for the host, so i need to use a smaller net for the VMs. I chose a `/112` for now, maybe i could use a bit bigger net if needed.

I guess the problem is the routing, not the container. Here is my setup:

Host:

```
# the host already has working ipv6, empty ip6tables FORWARD table with policy ACCEPT
ip -6 addr add prefix::1/112 dev lxcbr
ip -6 route show|grep prefix
# prefix::/112 dev lxcbr  proto kernel  metric 256
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding
# net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lxcbr.forwarding
# net.ipv6.conf.lxcbr.forwarding = 1
```

VM:

```
ip -6 addr add prefix::2/112 dev eth0
ip -6 route add default via fe80:: dev eth0 # routing via prefix::1 does not work either
ip -6 route show
# prefix::/112 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
# fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
# default via fe80:: dev eth0  metric 1024
```

Working (VM):

```
ping6 prefix::1 # host
```

Working (host):

```
ping6 prefix::2 # vm
```

Not working (VM):

```
ping6 google.com
# PING google.com (2a00:1450:4001:805::1007): 48 data bytes
# --- google.com ping statistics ---
# 7 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet los
```

tcpdump on host:

```
tcpdump -i lxcbr icmp6
# 13:20:44.088814 IP6 prefix::1 > fra07s32-in-x07.1e100.net: ICMP6, echo request, seq 0, length 56
# 13:20:45.089268 IP6 prefix::1 > fra07s32-in-x07.1e100.net: ICMP6, echo request, seq 1, length 56
# [...]
tcpdump -i eth0 icmp6
# [no output]
```

ip6tables with `-A FORWARD -j LOG` does not log any packets, too.

EDIT: Because everyone complains about nets smaller than `/64`: The problem persists with `/64` on the interface. The problem is, that no packets are getting into the `FORWARD` queue of iptables, when using a static route from one (virtual) interface to another (physical) interface.

The setup with a smaller net is what is would like to have, when its working, as my provider wants a rather big fee for more nets (near 50% of server rent). But for testing i can use the whole `/64` or big nets from `fd/8` if it helps for testing.

Comment: Get a larger prefix from your ISP.

Comment: This would not solve the problem, i even tried to put the whole /64 on the interface, the problem is the missing routing between the two interfaces, not the prefix size.

Comment: Maybe not, but you still need to do it. Breaking a /64 is only going to cause you more problems in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working ... but its still strange.

setting forwarding for "all", but then disable it for each individual interface works:

```
cd /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/
echo 1 >all/forwarding;for i in */forwarding;do test $i = all/forwarding || echo 0 > $i;done
```

doing the opposite (set all/forwarding to 0 and forwarding for every interface to 1) does not work.

Another interesting issue: Sometimes you need to add routes AFTER the interface is added to the bridge to make it work, same issue as here:
https://www.rivy.org/2013/02/ipv6-ping-sendmsg-network-is-down/

Thanks to jeff-loughridge for the docker link, the first section of this howto got me to this solution.

I am still investigating what exactly is happening here (and if it stays working), before i close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use your set-up in a production environment. As others mentioned, breaking up the /64 will have unanticipated implications. If you can't get more addresses from your provider, I recommend using NDP proxy to allow your containers in the /112 to reach the IPv6 internet. You can use an NDP proxy daemon or create static entries at the command line.

I wrote a detailed description of how to do this with docker [here](http://jeffloughridge.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/ipv6-in-docker-containers-on-digitalocean/). The same logic applies for lxc.

Comment: Of course you're right, that this is not the best situation, but the problem seems NOT to be in the small net, so this answer is not really helpful. I added an EDIT to the question and offer to test setups with bigger private IPv6-ranges.

Comment: I suggest you try the NDP proxy method before you label it unhelpful. In addition, I am not sure you understand the difference between having a /64 assigned to your provider-facing interface vs. having the provider route a /64 or larger to your host. You can do your testing on a DigitalOcean VM or Linode VM. Linode will route a /64 to your host upon email request. You can test the scenario with only a /64 on your provider-facing interface using either IaaS provider.

Comment: before making it too complicated (ndp proxy sounds like overkill to me) i would rather like to setup private ip-space on two virtual interface and test with this. I just want to get packets coming from ip-space1 on interface1 with target ip-space2 (on interface2) to get forwarded, which should be ordinary routing without any extras. With ipv4 its just having the correct route in the routing table (which is default, if you just want to route from one interface to another with the correct ip-space assigned). I guess this should work with v6 too, but there is some pitfall i overlooked.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a NAT scenario. Don't do this.

Comment: no, i do not want NAT. And i DO NOT WANT nat. Its like ``ip addr add fd00::/16 dev iface1;ip addr add fd01::/16 dev iface2`` and the routes ``ip route add fd00::/16 dev iface1;ip route add fd01::/16 dev iface2`` (which should be implicitly added by the ``ip addr``). But this requires forwarding from iface1 to iface2 and vice versa. Now the packets coming from ``iface1`` do never reach ``iface2``. or any local ip at this machine not assigned to ``iface1``.

Comment: How do you expect to reach the IPv6 internet?

Comment: in my final setup, i would reach it via defaultroute and all interfaces would have public ip space, but i just added this example as a minimal setup i can play with i.e. in a vm. If it works to send packets from one interface to another with private ip space, i the rest of setup is to replace private ips/routes by public ones.

Comment: @allo The issue is not so much the length of the prefix but rather the difference between a link prefix and a routed prefix. What you want to do requires a routed prefix. If all you have is a link prefix, then you cannot do, what you want to do, regardless of the prefix length. The NDP proxy approach is a hack, which can turn part of a link prefix into a routed prefix. It is inefficient and a waste of memory on the provider's router. It would be better for both you and the provider to use a real routed prefix.